# Execute & store result from command in C

Tags: php, c

I'm trying to test a php file from a C program(...)

Basically I have a filename that I want to check against php -l and store the output for further processing.

Comment: You want to compare the results of a php program (webpage?) to some output saved in a file?

Comment: No I want to make sure the php file doesnt have any errors, php -l checks for parse errors

Comment: So you just want to exec php -l against your path and store the output.

Comment: Yes but I want to store it in a variable in C because if there is an error I want to do something else..

Comment: Cant you redirect the result to a file and read that file? something like `system("php -l .. > tempfile");` and then open the file called tempfile and read it.

Comment: @Thrustmaster you want to post that as an answer?  I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution in that case would be to redirect the output to a file. And then read the file into an array. You then can have your further processing with the array.

Something like this(in C):

```
system("php -l yourfile.php > myfile");
FILE *f = fopen("myfile", "rb");
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
long pos = ftell(f);
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
char *array = malloc(pos);
fread(array, pos, 1, f);
fclose(f);

//your processing part here..

free(array); // free allocated memory
```

**Solution #2**: Invoke the PHP interpreter, and pipe the output to your program.
Something like the following in the console:

```
php -l yourfile.php | pathToYourCProgram
```

In the above case, you will read the output of PHP from stdin. You can read the entire input, and directly store it to an array.

Comment: Upvoted, as strictly spoken, this answers the question more closely than mine.

Comment: Writing to a named file on disk is always a security concern.

Answer (score 1):

you can use "popen" function. do man popen to understand the usage of popen. 1st argument of popen is the binary which you want to execute (i.e. "php -l" in your case), and 2nd argument is the mode (read/write). in your case file mode will be read. see the following code to understand how popen works, its fairly easy.

http://www.google.com/notebook/public/17135812868734162318/BDSUiDQoQ-ojrzeck

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If executing the php processor from your C program is not mandatory, you might want to consider the following completely different approach:

1. Make a small program that parses `stdin` for error messages and do some post processing. Let's call this program `check_errors`.
2. On the command line:

   `php -l thefile.php | check_errors`

   This catches the output of php and directs it to `check_errors`.

It's more Unix-like to build little tools that do one thing, and one thing only, but doing it very well. Using pipes and redirects one may sequence those programs, doing amazing and complex operations.